# Docker: enhancing containers

Tags: docker

I'm new to Docker and I'm still trying to get my head around how it should be used.

I have 2 questions, but first, let me give you some quick background:

I would like to create a project that uses R, Python and Scala. Based on what I've read, it is recommended to keep all 3 in separate containers.

so, my questions are:

1) Is there a way to somehow group multiple containers that are designed to be used by the same project?

2) Can combine several docker images available on Docker Hub? For example, there is an image designed for geospatial analysis in R, but also another R image that comes with pandoc for report generation -- can I somehow combine these into a single R container? Or would you recommend keeping them separated?

Many thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for `docker-compose`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) use docker compose  https://docs.docker.com/compose/

2) read both of their dockerfiles, learn how to write your own Dockerfile and create your own "combined image" https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

Comment: Thanks, it sounds like this is exactly what I'm looking for. One more question though: would you say it's easier to create a new custom docker image with everything you need in it, or is it better to create your project and then use docker compose to package together?

Comment: That depends. It's generally best practice to keep them separate, and they can network together. Though if it's just for development, you can do anything, including building everything in to one large image. Large images are not great though.